# Why is this double initialization with a comma illegal?

Tags: c++, comma-operator

I have three code snippets. This one:

```
1,7; //yes, that's all the code
```

compiles okay. This one:

```
double d = (1, 7);
```

also compiles okay. Yet this one:

```
double d = 1, 7;
```

fails to compile. gcc-4.3.4 says

> error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

and Visual C++ 10 says

> error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

Why such difference? Why don't all the three compile with `,` having the same effect in all three?

Comment: I think the grammar would be really quite hairy to treat `double d = 1, 7;` as a single declarator, with `1, 7` as the initializer expression, while treating `double d = 1, e = 7;` as two declarators. Or would you go even further, and say that if there already is an `e` in scope then `double d = 1, e = 7;` should *also* be treated as a single declarator, with initializer expression `1, e = 7`? I see a lot of potential for confusion, just to save typing a couple of parens in the case `double d = (1, 7);` which is pointless anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first two cases, the statements are using C++'s [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

In the latter case, comma is being used as variable separate and the compiler is expecting you to declare multiple identifiers; the comma is not being used as the operator here.

The last case is similar to something like:

```
float x,y;
float a = 10, b = 20;
```

When you do this:

```
double d = 1, 7;
```

The compiler expects a variable identifier and not a numeric constant. Hence 7 is illegal here.

However when you do this:

```
double d = (1,7);
```

the normal comma operator is being used: 1 gets evaluated and discard while 7 is stored in d.

Comment: +1: Yes, the answer is essentially "because the grammar says so".

Comment: "the comma operator is not being used in the way it normally is" - to be precise, that comma token is not the comma operator at all. It's a separator between two declarators, and `7` is not a valid declarator.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that in `1, 7;` and `(1, 7)` you have expressions where a comma operator is allowed.

Your last example

```
double d = 1, 7;
```

is a declaration, where the comma isn't an operator but a separator. The compiler exepcts something like

```
double d = 1, e = 7;
```

which would be a correct variable declaration.

Note that the comma is sometimes an operator (in expressions), but is also used as a separator in other places like parameter lists in function declarations.

Answer (score 3):

1. `double d = (1, 7);` Here the `(1, 7)` will be evaluated
   first; the comma works as **sequential-evaluation operator**, and
   `7` will be assigned to `d`.
2. `double d = 1, 7;` In this case there is a problem: the part
   before the comma means you declare a double and set its value, but
   the part after the comma is **meaningless**, because it's just a single
   integer constant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the last one is treated as (incorrect) declaration line: `(double d = 1), (7)`

Comment: If that were the case, it should compile, just as 1,7; does.

Comment: 1,7; is basically a very simple statement, so it is allowed by compiler... Your last line is an incorrect declaration.

Comment: The line is being treated as `double (d = 1), (7);` and as a variable can't start with a number `double 7` is a syntax error