# a parenthesis expression assigned to single lvalue

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, comma-operator

Why does this code compile ?

```
int X = (2,4);
```

I compiled this line with [c++ replit](https://replit.com/languages/cpp)

the second value (4) is assigned to X

Comment: Read about [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). Also see [how `double d = (1, 7);` work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519884/why-is-this-double-initialization-with-a-comma-illegal).

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to "search and then research" and you'll find plenty of related SO questions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initializing expression is a praimary expression with the comma operator

```
int X = (2,4);
```

Its value is the value of the second operand of the comma operator.

In fact this declaration is equivalent to the declaration

```
int X = 4;
```

because the first operand has no side effect.

From the C++17 Standard (8.19 Comma operator)

> 1 The comma operator groups left-to-right.

```
expression: assignment-expression
expression , assignment-expression
```

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;
> the left expression is a discarded-value expression (Clause 8). Every
> value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
> is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated
> with the right expression. The type and value of the result are the
> type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value
> category as its right operand, and is a bit-field if its right operand
> is a bit-field. If the right operand is a temporary expression (15.2),
> the result is a temporary expression.

Answer (score 0):

It will compile in c++. The only value that is applied is the last one when you use a parenthesis expression with multiple values inside, however all values will be evaluated which means you can do things like this in very specific cases:

```
int a, b;
a = (b = 3, 5);  // assigns 3 to b and 5 to a
```